# Loading Functions from Github into R Studio

Tags: r, function, github

I am trying to follow this tutorial :

http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/437544_1feb48fe03234a3abecf81726c1c3905.html#theDetails

The author of this tutorial created a github site for this tutorial with definitions of r functions required:

https://github.com/haiderstats/ISDEvaluation

Currently, I am manually copying and pasting functions from here into R. Is there a quicker way to load all these supporting functions into R at once?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to install `git` if you don't have it already.

Once installed, from your terminal run the command `git clone https://github.com/haiderstats/ISDEvaluation`.

This will retrieve all files from the repository, and you will then be able to open any of the R files in RStudio as they will be on your local machine.